# r wide data to widish and long

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm still coming to grips with how to best manipulate data using r...

If possible I'd like to do this with tidyr or dplyr packages/functions.

I have some data coming in like this:

```
cost <- tibble(
  v1=c('some text1','group1','name','date',c(runif(3),NA,NA,NA)), 
  v2=c('some text1','group1','name','value',c(runif(3),NA,NA,NA)), 
  v3=c('some text2','group1','name2','date',c(runif(4),NA,NA)), 
  v4=c('some text2','group1','name2','value',c(runif(4),NA,NA)),
  v5=c('some text3','group2','name3','date',runif(6)), 
  v6=c('some text3','group2','name3','value',runif(6))
  )
cost[] <- lapply( cost, factor)
> glimpse(cost)
Observations: 10
Variables: 6
$ v1 <fctr> some text1, group1, name, date, 0.924267573514953, 0.203127129469067, 0.0484973937273026, NA, NA, NA
$ v2 <fctr> some text1, group1, name, value, 0.712983385194093, 0.994925277773291, 0.0975768479984254, NA, NA, NA
$ v3 <fctr> some text2, group1, name2, date, 0.188781834673136, 0.859566977713257, 0.739685433451086, 0.2719707184...
$ v4 <fctr> some text2, group1, name2, value, 0.416961463401094, 0.558401603251696, 0.334375116974115, 0.195782373...
$ v5 <fctr> some text3, group2, name3, date, 0.857840840239078, 0.545017473166808, 0.209725016728044, 0.5044016360...
$ v6 <fctr> some text3, group2, name3, value, 0.551554219797254, 0.529705551918596, 0.258927160175517, 0.517376250...
```

I'd like to make it longer, and wider.  That is the first 3 rows, move into 3 columns, and have their values duplicated along side the data for that 'name.
I'd also like to drop the missing values, they may not be NA, it looks like they are just empty (these were `read.csv` in from CSV file)

```
> cost <- tibble(
    name=c('name', 'name','name'),
    desc=c('some text1', 'some text1', 'some text1'),
    group=c('group2', 'group2', 'group2'),
    date=c('dd-mm-yy', 'dd-mm-yy', 'dd-mm-yy'),
    value=c(runif(1), runif(1), runif(1)) 
   )
> cost
# A tibble: 3 x 5
   name       desc  group     date      value
  <chr>      <chr>  <chr>    <chr>      <dbl>
1  name some text1 group2 dd-mm-yy 0.04565986
2  name some text1 group2 dd-mm-yy 0.82689013
3  name some text1 group2 dd-mm-yy 0.67433167
```

Comment: Can u show the expected output?  You said the first 3 rows, which include `sometext` as well. What is `desc`?

Comment: Do you mean `t(cost)`?

Comment: I have added the example output.  There are some subtleties in this problem.  No I don't mean `t(cost)`, hopefully the additional data makes that clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your desired outcome. However, if I am wrong, please mockup what you are actually trying to get out of these data.

For this, I am using several functions from `tidyr`.

First, I am going to create new column labels that collapse the four rows of header information that you have. Basically, I am taking the first four rows, collapsing each into a single string (with a three underscore spacer, which is unlikely to occur in your actual data), then converting the data.frame to a character vector.

```
myColNames <-
  cost[1:4,] %>%
  summarise_all(paste, collapse = "___") %>%
  c %>%
  unlist
```

Generates

```
                                   v1                                    v2                                    v3 
  "some text1___group1___name___date"  "some text1___group1___name___value"  "some text2___group1___name2___date" 
                                   v4                                    v5                                    v6 
"some text2___group1___name2___value"  "some text3___group2___name3___date" "some text3___group2___name3___value"
```

Next, I can remove the rows I just used to make the column names, and insert the names as columns instead (using `setNames`). Next, I added an index to link the data on a row together (when it is from the same header). Then, I can `gather` the dataset into a long format and `separate` the column headers I created into their components. Finally, I can `spread` the date and value entries into separate columns (matched on the same row because of the `rowIdx`) and filter out the missing observations.

```
cost[-(1:4), ] %>%
  ## This step is only necessary if the data
  ## were imported as factors instead of as character
  mutate_all(funs(as.character)) %>%
  setNames(myColNames) %>%
  mutate(rowIdx = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(key, tempVal, -rowIdx) %>%
  separate(key, c("Text", "Group", "Name", "toSpread"), sep = "___") %>%
  spread(toSpread, tempVal) %>%
  filter(!is.na(date))
```

returns

```
   rowIdx       Text  Group  Name               date               value
    <int>      <chr>  <chr> <chr>              <chr>               <chr>
 1      1 some text1 group1  name  0.601032865699381   0.320803644834086
 2      1 some text2 group1 name2  0.755003974540159   0.724728998960927
 3      1 some text3 group2 name3  0.782037091907114   0.642663416918367
 4      2 some text1 group1  name 0.0365895153954625   0.131514045642689
 5      2 some text2 group1 name2 0.0913304232526571   0.198074621148407
 6      2 some text3 group2 name3  0.690302846953273   0.915490478742868
 7      3 some text1 group1  name  0.912119234679267   0.474282702198252
 8      3 some text2 group1 name2  0.909885906847194   0.125321796629578
 9      3 some text3 group2 name3  0.883244396885857   0.850464047864079
10      4 some text2 group1 name2  0.894993636989966   0.443535323021933
11      4 some text3 group2 name3  0.674304561689496   0.823389955097809
12      5 some text3 group2 name3  0.700140621513128   0.458009321708232
13      6 some text3 group2 name3   0.19869831786491 0.00457167089916766
```

Comment: Wow. That was not at all obvious.  Thanks.

Comment: `read.csv` makes this even more subtle.... by converting everything to a factor - this wreaks havoc with the contents of `value` columns in the above code.

Comment: Yes, if you use data that are fundamentally different than the sample data you show, there will be problems. My guess is that two of the columns in your dataset have identical values for the rows that you are pasting together. You should be able to address this by adding a unique value to the end of the string (e.g., the three-underscore separator followed by an index). Just make sure that either the data in those columns really do mean the same thing or that the index lets you figure out what it meant. Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.csv` (or `read_csv` from `readr`) to avoid factors

Comment: Apologies.  I hadn't realised the structure when I posted the question.  I did resolve the issues pretty much in the way you note.  If you add `mutate_all(funs(as.character)) %>%` as the first step i.e. before `setNames(...)` then I'll be able to accept this as the answer.

Comment: @Hedgehog, I added the change back to characters. The conversion to factors is a problem often enough that it is worth evaluating your data loading steps and considering a change to not automatically convert all strings to factors (using the tips from my other comment).